# TYPO3 produces wrong moved location

Tags: php, typo3

we are running a TYPO3 host with realurl and TYPO3 version 4.4.0 - now something strange happens, if a page isn't found

TYPO3 throws a 302 (moved) - which seems the normal behaviour of TYPO3 - but the location for the moved document isn't my domain something like this is produced
`http://otherdomain.com/servlet/domain/myrealdomain.de/404`

What is happening here?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to complete this:

this behaviour is produced by the system dns config. the `resolv.conf` had an entry like:

```
search otherdomain.com
```

which lead to my strange problem. after removing the search line everything works now like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend the extension UrlTool. 404 handling works fine with realUrl.
http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/aeurltool/current/